# Database query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 database
1st Database name : xyz
table name : emp
here is my table emp

```
userid       create
a.b           a.b
b.c           a.b
c.d           b.c
```

2nd Database name : abc
table name : sal
here is my table sal

```
date         userid
4/20/2014     a.b
4/16/2014     b.c
4/17/2014     c.d
```

i want that
if userid is a.b , it check emp table and a.b is the creator so it check data for a.b and b.c also because a.b is the creator of b.c and result is like that

```
date         userid
4/20/2014     a.b
4/16/2014     b.c
```

if userid is b.c , it check emp table and b.c is the creator so it check data for b.c and c.d also because b.c is the creator of c.d and result is like that

```
date         userid
4/16/2014     b.c
4/17/2014     c.d
```

if my userid is c.d , it check emp table and c.d is not the creator so it check only data for c.d and result is like that

```
date         userid
4/17/2014     c.d
```

Is that any way to do this with Query.
I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: strange ids a.b, a.c. why did you make them that way ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev its only example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do?

```
use abc;
go

select s.date, s.userid
from dbo.sal s
where s.userid in (
    select e.userid 
    from xyz.dbo.emp e
    where 'a.b' in (e.userid, e.[create])
)
```

This assumes you're in the context of `abc` database, and that the security between the databases is set correctly.

Comment: not work, these two table "sal" and "emp" have different database.

Comment: OK, just put whatevever schema the `sal` table is in instead of `dbo`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. I have altered your table names and data slightly. If I recall correctly 'CREATE' and 'DATE' are reserved words in T-SQL and should be avoided as column names. The select statement I think that you want is a join of the emp and sal tables you want any rows where the given user id is a match for userid column value or the creator.

I will assume that the emp table is in a database named db1 in a schema named hr.  I will assume that the sal table is in a database named db2 in a schema named erp.  In MS SQL Server one can refer to an object as [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[ObjectName] to refer to an object in a different database or schema, or use [Schema].[ObjectName] for a different schema in the same database.

```
USE db1;    
GO

CREATE TABLE hr.emp (
        userid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , creator VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    );

GO

USE db2;

GO


  CREATE TABLE erp.sal (
        userid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,saldate DATE NOT NULL

    );

GO

INSERT INTO db1.hr.emp ( userid, creator )
VALUES ( 'a', 'a' );

INSERT INTO db1.hr.emp ( userid, creator )
VALUES( 'b', 'a' );

INSERT INTO db1.hr.emp ( userid, creator )
VALUES ( 'c' , 'b'  );


INSERT INTO db2.erp.sal ( saldate, userid )
VALUES ( '4/20/2014' , 'a' );


INSERT INTO db2.erp.sal ( saldate, userid )
VALUES ( '4/16/2014', 'b'  );


INSERT INTO db2.erp.sal ( saldate, userid )
VALUES ( '4/17/2014' , 'c' );



-- query 
DECLARE @userid VARCHAR(10);
SET @userid = 'c';  -- plug your desired userid value in here

SELECT S.saldate, S.userid
FROM db1.hr.emp AS E
    INNER JOIN db2.erp.sal AS S
        ON ( E.userid = S.userid )
WHERE ( E.creator =  @userid OR E.userid =  @userid );
```

Comment: these two table are not the same database

Comment: @user3441151 I have amended my example adding the database and schema references to give an example of a cross database query.